# How to make certain nodes have no circle around it using tkz-graph?

Tags: graphs, tkz-graph

I'm trying to draw a simple hierarchical structure using tkz-graph:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi, x=0, y=4.5]{pi}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=-4.5, y=0]{pi_32_1}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=-3.5, y=0]{pi_32_2}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=-2.5, y=0]{pi_32_3}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=-1.5, y=0]{pi_32_4}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=1.5, y=0]{pi_32_5}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=2.5, y=0]{pi_32_6}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=3.5, y=0]{pi_32_7}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=4.5, y=0]{pi_32_8}
\Vertex[Math, L=\cdots, x=-0, y=0]{dots}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{16}}, x=-4, y=1.25]{pi_16_1}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{16}}, x=-2, y=1.25]{pi_16_2}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{16}}, x=2, y=1.25]{pi_16_3}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{16}}, x=4, y=1.25]{pi_16_4}
\Vertex[Math, L=\cdots, x=-0, y=1.25]{dots}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{8}}, x=-3, y=2.5]{pi_8_1}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{8}}, x=3, y=2.5]{pi_8_2}
\Vertex[Math, L=\cdots, x=-0, y=2.5]{dots}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}, x=-1.25, y=3.75]{pi_2_1}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}, x=1.25, y=3.75]{pi_2_2}
\SetUpEdge[style={->}]
\Edge(pi_32_1)(pi_16_1)
\Edge(pi_32_2)(pi_16_1)
\Edge(pi_32_3)(pi_16_2)
\Edge(pi_32_4)(pi_16_2)
\Edge(pi_32_5)(pi_16_3)
\Edge(pi_32_6)(pi_16_3)
\Edge(pi_32_7)(pi_16_4)
\Edge(pi_32_8)(pi_16_4)
\Edge(pi_16_1)(pi_8_1)
\Edge(pi_16_2)(pi_8_1)
\Edge(pi_16_3)(pi_8_2)
\Edge(pi_16_4)(pi_8_2)  
\Edge[label=...](pi_8_1)(pi_2_1)
\Edge[label=...](pi_8_2)(pi_2_2)
\Edge(pi_2_1)(pi)
\Edge(pi_2_2)(pi)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This currently gives me:

[image]

I just want the vertices with dots in to not have a circle around them. Is there a way I can do this? Or is there a different way to have dots to 'fill in spaces'.

In this graph, on the lowest level, there are 32 nodes, the next 16, and so on til 1. But I want to just use dots as fillers so I don't need to draw the full graph, since it should be simple to see how the graph can be completed.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Add option `draw=none` to the `...` nodes.

Comment: @JouleV Thanks for the response! how do I add an option to these nodes?

Comment: USe `\node at (0,0) {$\ldots$};` instead of `\Vertex[Math, L=\cdots, x=-0, y=0]{dots}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You only need to do what @JouleV was suggesting: put these things in a scope in which `draw` is switched off: `\begin{scope}[VertexStyle/.style = {draw=none}]
\Vertex[Math, L=\cdots, x=-0, y=0]{dots}
\Vertex[Math, L=\cdots, x=-0, y=2.5]{dots}
\Vertex[Math, L=\cdots, x=-0, y=1.25]{dots}
\end{scope}`. You will get more enthusiastic support if you provide us with an MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions by @marmot and @JouleV, here the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi, x=0, y=4.5]{pi}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=-4.5, y=0]{pi_32_1}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=-3.5, y=0]{pi_32_2}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=-2.5, y=0]{pi_32_3}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=-1.5, y=0]{pi_32_4}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=1.5, y=0]{pi_32_5}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=2.5, y=0]{pi_32_6}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=3.5, y=0]{pi_32_7}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{32}}, x=4.5, y=0]{pi_32_8}
\begin{scope}[VertexStyle/.style = {draw=none}]
\Vertex[Math, L=\cdots, x=-0, y=0]{dots}
\end{scope}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{16}}, x=-4, y=1.25]{pi_16_1}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{16}}, x=-2, y=1.25]{pi_16_2}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{16}}, x=2, y=1.25]{pi_16_3}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{16}}, x=4, y=1.25]{pi_16_4}
\begin{scope}[VertexStyle/.style = {draw=none}]
\Vertex[Math, L=\cdots, x=-0, y=1.25]{dots}
\end{scope}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{8}}, x=-3, y=2.5]{pi_8_1}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{8}}, x=3, y=2.5]{pi_8_2}
\begin{scope}[VertexStyle/.style = {draw=none}]
\Vertex[Math, L=\cdots, x=-0, y=2.5]{dots}
\end{scope}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}, x=-1.25, y=3.75]{pi_2_1}
\Vertex[Math, L=\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}, x=1.25, y=3.75]{pi_2_2}
\SetUpEdge[style={->}]
\Edge(pi_32_1)(pi_16_1)
\Edge(pi_32_2)(pi_16_1)
\Edge(pi_32_3)(pi_16_2)
\Edge(pi_32_4)(pi_16_2)
\Edge(pi_32_5)(pi_16_3)
\Edge(pi_32_6)(pi_16_3)
\Edge(pi_32_7)(pi_16_4)
\Edge(pi_32_8)(pi_16_4)
\Edge(pi_16_1)(pi_8_1)
\Edge(pi_16_2)(pi_8_1)
\Edge(pi_16_3)(pi_8_2)
\Edge(pi_16_4)(pi_8_2)
\Edge[label=...](pi_8_1)(pi_2_1)
\Edge[label=...](pi_8_2)(pi_2_2)
\Edge(pi_2_1)(pi)
\Edge(pi_2_2)(pi)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]